# How add android ssl certificate for https request in ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

In ionic simulator all http and https working fine but in real device release version its stop working.

Many people adviced to add SSL certificate for release version but I dont know how to add this ?

I have tries all this to make https request ?

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Also added whitelist plugin but not working.

Also tried this but not working

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Comment: refer this please http://www.thomasmaximini.com/2015/01/23/getting-started-with-crosswalk-in-ionic.html

Comment: I dont want to use crosswalk. Is there any way to add ssl certificate or make https requests ?

Comment: Then you should use http Interceptor

Comment: What you have to do is to use a proper trusted certificate on your server, not on your app. You can make users install your bad certificate from the app, but on android 4.4 and greater they will get a security warning on the device all the time

Comment: but in my case we are using trusted certificate but still giving me status code = -1 for https requests

Comment: @jcesarmobile What do you mean? I'm new to ionic and working with a couple of other developers on an app (I'm the back-end developer/learning systems and servers), and trying to figure out what I need to do to have a secure login page. Are you saying that we need the SSL on the server and not the app for this intention? and if so, why?

Comment: @user3654055 if you use https, your server has to have a good certificate installed, if your device doesn't trust that certificate it won't connect

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is the most common issue raised by all the developers.. Finally I found the answer and here it is..

SSL certificate is enough for a website to connect via HTTPS but coming to hybrid Apps like App build on ionic, SSL itself is not enough and you need a code signing certificate which costs few hundred bucks..

Other alternative is using a self signed certificate which you ca create FREE, here also you can able to connect to ionic web version via HTTPS but again after compiling, the apk file get halted to connect to DB server..

Here is the trick where you can add the HTTPS port or HTTP api link in the services using self signed certification..

Exactly follow the commands:

- ionic serve
- ionic build
- ionic build --prod
- cordova platform add android

After this, stop compiling and relax .. Now you will find a folder named platform as the path is as follows 
project/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java

DO THE FOLLOWING MODIFICATION AS IT IS

```html
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
  final String packageName = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName();
  final PackageManager pm = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();

  ApplicationInfo appInfo;
  try {
    appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
      // debug = true
      handler.proceed();
      return;
    } else {
      // debug = false
      // THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO CHANGE:
      // 1. COMMENT THIS LINE
      // super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
      // 2. ADD THESE TWO LINES
      // ---->
      handler.proceed();
      return;
      // <----
    }
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // When it doubt, lock it out!
    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
  }
}
```

THEN FINALLY

- cordova build --release android

After this, the usual commands jarsiner and zipalign

you apk should run in HTTPS port in SSL withh your self signed certificate..

Comment: Well, this is not a solution, but a workaround. You are just disabling completely any verification of the certificate trust, so in effect you are exposing yourself to man-in-the-middle type of attacks. What I would like is a way to trust only _my_ self signed certificate on the device, not trusting any certificate.