# ionic 4 app not working correctly on other android devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

i'm building ionic 4 app and install it on my device it works fine
[image: this on my device]

but when i try to install on other devices, it looks like this
[image: this on my device]

i've tried to debug this problem with chrome but everything works fine.
images and texts are from json file and not showing up, i think maybe it's because android version i use is different, anyone know what to do?

Comment: is there a repo to test the code? or a debug-apk?

Comment: i can provide you the apk, wait

Comment: http://youthscarf.id/mobile/app-debug1.apk

Comment: "It works fine" does not sound like you have any problem after all?

Comment: yeah, i don't have problem on my device. but when i install it on other device, it looks like the screenshot i provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is an error I am getting from your provided .apk file. This is a very common issue. To get data from the server your using URL `http://mobile.youthscarf.id/ionic/link_data.php` To avoid this error I will recommend you to use URL starts with `https://`. according to the new android security update we have to use certified URL. You can get free SSL for testing purposes from https://www.sslforfree.com/

Comment: link to json file is http, do you mean change it to https?

Comment: Yes, all server links your using in add should start with `https://` (including image URL)

Comment: Direct change from `http://` to `https://` won't work in your case because you have to apply SSL certificate first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40147383/how-add-android-ssl-certificate-for-https-request-in-ionic do you mean like this?

Comment: or do you have a link to maybe tutorial or something?

Comment: tutorial for what..?